# Dual monitor over network with Windows Host and Mac client?

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for something like MaxiVista that lets you extend your monitor to a second computer monitor. However Maxivista is only Windows base. My main computer is Windows 7 and the other computer I'm trying to connect to is a Mac. Note I am not trying to share my keyboard or mouse, I want to use the Mac as a third display.

Answer (score 1):

I try several things and I found a working solution using [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) :

**On the Mac computer :**

- Download [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).
- Copy Wine to Applications folder and start it.
- You do not need to install any WineTricks, just close that window.
- Add a new prefix (that is where the fake C drive will be created) then wait until its successful creation.
- Close all Wine related windows.
- Download [MaxiVista 32-bit](http://www.maxivista.com/download.htm).
- Unzip and double click `Maxivista_Setup_SecondaryPC.exe` (this should open Wine)
- On the appearing Wine window, choose *Run directly in :* then click Go.
- Proceed to MaxiVista install in Wine environment.
- Dont care about the *Unable to execute file C:\windows\system32\netsh* error.
- Turn on MaxiVista autostart.
- Turn off Firewall, if started.
- Go to X11 Preferences, Output tab then activate *Full-screen mode*.
- Toggle *Full-screen mode* <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>.
- You'll see a black&white background and a little window with MaxiVista icon in it.

**On the PC computer :**

- Download and install [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/download.htm).
- Configure it as needed.
- When your wallpaper appears on the Mac, stretch the window on the Mac to fit your screen.

I know this isn't really full screen, but it's the best I can do. (You'll only see the top bar and arrows on the right/down)

Maybe, you can try to better simulate full screen mode with plugins like [MegaZoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html), but I don't know if this works.